# Dictionaries with lists as values: how to retrieve the key given one value

Tags: python

I have a Python dictionary which looks like this:

```
alphabetic_dict = {
'a':['apple', 'ant', 'atlas'],
'b':['bee', 'beer','bat'],
'c':['car', 'cash', 'computer']
}
```

What I want to do is, given one of the values within a list, print the corresponding key. For example, if I write `car`, I want my program to output something like `That value corresponds to 'c'`. It might seem a silly thing, but I've never worked with a dictionary containing lists as values, so I'm very confused.

Comment: What if more than two lists contain the same element? If you're sure that's never the case, consider making a reversed dictionary that looks like `{'apple':'a', 'ant':'a', 'atlas':'a', 'bee':'b', ...}`

Comment: If the key is the first letter of the word, just take the first letter of the word...

Comment: @Taegyung elements are not repeated, so that wouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the value (which is a list) for the thing you;re looking for

```
for k, v in alphabetic_dict.items()
    if 'car' in v:
       print k
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input = 'c'
for key, values in alphabetic_dict.items():
    if input in values:
        print(f'That value corresponds to {key}')
```

This uses f-strings which were introduced in python 3.6